# Jest spy not getting initialized/Mocked

Tags: node.js, types, jestjs

I am trying to write test for my sample app, The structure of the app is as follows

```
src/
    Module A
    Module B

Module B has 2 exported functions

const function2 = ()=>{

//Calculations

if(function3()){

//Transform
}
return obj;
}

const function3=()=>{
return true/false;
}

export{function2,function3}
```

I am writing test for a function in Module A. Function on Module A uses a Function in module B lets call it function 2 and function 2 internally calls function 3 to compute some data. I am trying to mock function 3 return values in different test but it is not getting mocked.

Tried this

```
import * as Module2Handler from '../module2'
import * as Module1Handler from '../module1'
const function3Spy = jest.spyOn('Module2Handler','function3');

describe('Test for modules 1',()=>{

it('Return object with property a',async()=>{
function3Spy.mockResolvedValue(true);
expect(await Module1Handler.function1({x:'123'})).toMatchObject({a:1})
})

})
```

The test is failing and when i am printing value of function 3 in function 2 , it is coming out to be false.
Also Tested expect(function3Spy).toBeCalledTimes(1) which also fails

Jest Version in package.json 24.9.0
"typescript": "4.5.4"

Comment: Your description states ```I am writing test for a function in Module A```, but your tests are importing ```module2```. I don't think the description and the example code are correlating.

Comment: fixed thanks for pointing out the error

Comment: Can you try to change your imports from ```import * as Module2Handler from '../module2'``` to ```import Module2Handler from '../module2'``` syntax. And then change ```const function3Spy = jest.spyOn('Module2Handler','function3');``` to ```const function3Spy = jest.spyOn(Module2Handler,'function3');```